# ¿Por qué en JS la operación: 010 - 03 = 5?

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro realizando unas preguntas de conocimiento de JS dispuestas en esta página: https://jsisweird.com/. Me pareció bastante extraño que la sustracción de

```
010 - 03 = 5
```

y su inverso

```
010 + 03 = ?
```

no le encuentro una explicación aún, y tal vez alguien sabe la explicación este extraño comportamiento.

Comment: En la página que enlazas, la pregunta es `010 - 03`. Tú has cambiado la operación por una suma. Te invito a corregir la pregunta, ya que está mal redactada. Saludos

Answer (score 7):

La respuesta correcta es `11`.

#### Explicación

Javascript soporta [octales](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#n%C3%BAmeros_octales):

> La sintaxis de números octales utiliza un cero a la izquierda. Si los dígitos después del `0` están fuera del rango de `0` a `7`, el número se interpretará como un número decimal.

El sistema octal *"es como el binario"*, pero en lugar de usar como base `2`, se usa como base `8`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
01   === 1 * 8exp0
010  === 1 * 8exp1 + 0 * 8exp0 = 8
```

*Nota:* `8expX` significa `8` elevado al exponente `X` o en Javascript sería `Math.pow(8, X)`

Entonces si:

```
010 = 8
 03 = 3

010 + 03 = 11
```

#### Demo:

```js
console.log('010 =', 010);
console.log('03 =', 03);
console.log('010 + 03 =', 010 + 03);
```